# the meaning of bits in rawToBits?

Tags: r

```
> as.raw(15)
[1] 0f
> rawToBits(as.raw(15))
[1] 01 01 01 01 00 00 00 00
> rawToBits(0f)
Error: unexpected symbol in "rawToBits(0f"
> rawToBits("0f")
Error in rawToBits("0f") : argument 'x' must be a raw vector
> rawToBits("0x0f")
Error in rawToBits("0x0f") : argument 'x' must be a raw vector
```

I have some problems to ask:
1) is that `0f` a raw type data?
2) why `rawToBits(as.raw(15))` can not get `11110000`? the 15 is not `11110000`?
15=0f=1*2^0+1*2^1+1*2^2+1*2^3

What is the meaning of `0` in  [1] `0`1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  when you input `rawToBits(as.raw(1))`?
In the manual ,i get `a raw vector with entries 0 or 1`,what is the meaning of`entries 0 or 1`.
Why `rawToBits(as.raw(2))` is not `10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just typing 0f doesn't give you something of type raw.

```
> str(as.raw(15))
 raw 0f
> str(0f)
Error: unexpected symbol in "str(0f"
> str("0f")
 chr "0f"
```

If you want to know what's going on with the bits you could try some other values to get a better idea what is going on

```
> rawToBits(as.raw(1))
[1] 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> rawToBits(as.raw(2))
[1] 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00
> rawToBits(as.raw(4))
[1] 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00
> rawToBits(as.raw(8))
[1] 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00
> rawToBits(as.raw(1 + 2 + 4 + 8))
[1] 01 01 01 01 00 00 00 00
> rawToBits(as.raw(15))
[1] 01 01 01 01 00 00 00 00
```

Comment: What is the meaning of 0 in [1] 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 when you input rawToBits(as.raw(1))?
In the manual ,i get a raw vector with entries 0 or 1,what is the meaning ofentries 0 or 1.
Why rawToBits(as.raw(2)) is not 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00?